# Simplifying or finding a recurrence for $T(n,r)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r} \frac{1}{n-i}\binom{n-2}{i-1}\binom{n-1}{i}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let 
$$T(n,r)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r} \frac{1}{n-i}\binom{n-2}{i-1}\binom{n-1}{i}$$

I want to simplfy or find recurrence for $T(n,r)$.

Comment: Perhaps you can try this. Recall that: $\binom{n-2}{i-1}=\frac{n-i}{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}=\frac{n-i}{n-1}\binom{n-1}{n-i}$. Thus, $T(n,r)=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\binom{n-1}{n-i}\binom{n-1}{i}}$, which looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple expresses it in terms of a hypergeometric function:

$$-{\frac { \left( n-r-1 \right) 
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,-n+2+r,1+r-n;\,1+r,2+r;\,1)} \left( \Gamma \left( 
n \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( 1+r \right) }{ \left( \Gamma \left( n-r
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( n-1 \right)  \left( \Gamma \left( 2+r
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}+{\frac {\Gamma \left( -1+2\,n \right) }{n
 \left( \Gamma \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$